# How call jScript function in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this function in.js file:

```
 function setValue(amount) {
    if (amount === 0) {
        .....
    loanDriver._mem.loanValue = amount;
}
```

I like to call this in my MVC view and send this value to it : Model.ApprovedAmount

I tried this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setValue(@Html.Raw(Model.ApprovedAmount))
</script>
```

it is not working.

How I can do that?

Comment: Define "not working".  What is the resulting client-side code here?  How does it fail?  Is there an error on the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: You'll need to ensure that the script that contains your `setValue()` function is defined prior to the `<script>` tag that contains your calling function. If that is the case, then you should be able to simply call `setValue(@Model.ApprovedAmount);` and it should work as expected (depending on what your ApprovedAmount value looks like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code likely doesn't need the `Html.Raw()` call, but besides that it at least appears to be correct :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setValue(@Model.ApprovedAmount)
</script>
```

There are a few things that you may want to look into to further troubleshoot this issue :

**Check Your References**

Firstly, make sure that the Javascript file that defines your `setValue()` function is being referenced prior to your existing `<script>` tag shown in your example. This is important as otherwise your page won't know what `setValue()` 
is:

```
<script src='your-file-with-setvalue-defined.js'></script>
<script>
    setValue(@Model.ApprovedAmount);
</script>
```

**Use the Developer Tools**

Check the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser, specifically the Network and Console tabs. These will reveal additional details about what exactly is going wrong (i.e. 404 errors, undefined functions, bad arguments, etc.).

**Use the `debugger`**

Consider using the `debugger` keyword within your `setValue()` function to see if it's being called and what the value that is being passed in looks like :

```
<script>
    // Run this with your Developer Tools open and step into the function to
    // see more
    debugger;
    setValue(@Model.ApprovedAmount);
</script>
```

**Example**

You can [see a complete example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pzCu8i) and seen below that demonstrates the basic idea behind this working as expected :

```
// HomeController.cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModel(){ Amount = 42 });
    }
}

// SampleViewModel.cs
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

// Index.cshtml
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Calling Function From Model</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function setValue(amount) {
                alert(amount);
            }
            setValue(@Model.Amount);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are just doing it on the view, you can do something like this:

`<text><b>some text:</b> </text> @Html.TextBox("something", null, new { "callsomefunction"() })`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, simply I had to use name of the file dot name of the function and it worked. jsfile.setValue(@Model.ApprovedAmount);